# mysql query locking tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

Hi Is there a way of checking which query is locking tables in mysql? We can Identify which tables are locked however Its difficult to find the query that is locking tables. We have tried show processlist, show engine innodb status, and also looked at some tables such INNODB_TRX and INNODB_LOCKS. Is there a specific method that can point out what is causing the locks?

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access to mysql service:

```
#mysql -uroot
#mysql> SET global log_output = 'table';
#mysql> SET global general_log = 1;
```

reload site or do something that locks table

```
#mysql> SET global general_log = 0;
```

And next inspect table `mysql.general_log`

If you haven't root access to mysql service set in `root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`:

```
protected $_debug = true;
protected $_logAllQueries = true;
```

After reload page you'll get query log in `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log`

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here, but "SHOW PROCESS LIST" DOES show you the query that's locking the table, although not show you the full query.

If you want to see the full query, you must execute "SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST".

If this does not help you please provide more info (or perhaps my english need some polish and did not understand the question).

EDIT: some grammar