# Magento SQLSTATE Column Not Found Unknown column 'customer_group_id' in 'field list'

Tags: sql, database, magento

When duplicate a product:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_group_id' in 'field list'. Database has Customer_Group Table, what do you suggest? Thank you in advance, regards.

Comment: 1. try to get sql query with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747993/mysql-query-locking-tables 2. try to disable all modules and locate exception place

Comment: Thanks P0ZiTR0N. I looked at your post link but don't understand what I have to do in database, in you could please be more specific, thank you.

Comment: 1. Enable mysql query log with one of ways described in that link. If you can realize what query is going wrong values you can move forward. Otherwise step to 2. disable all third-party modules via setting `true=>false` in `/etc/modules/*.xml` files

Comment: Thank you. I noticed issue only happens when product has advanced attributes on it (third party extension). If not, duplicate works ok.

Comment: Next step is contact developer of extension or try to resolve it by inspecting its dataflow

Comment: Thank you P0ZiTR0N. I will contact the developer. Best Regards.